# Path Not Found Error appears Randomly in Windows Terminal

Tags: terminal, path, windows-11

Recently a windows terminal window opens with a "System cannot find the path specified [process exited code 1]. This is not associated with running an application but rather appears periodically. This does not seem to coincide with any errors in the event viewer. I cannot associate the error with processes running in task manager. I have tried scannow and DISM RestoreHealth but no problems detected. I have checked all the paths in my environmental variables twice and they are all valid paths. If I leave my laptop running unattended I can return to find 10-20 terminal windows with the cannot find path specified error. I am unsure how to proceed to determine the cause. My laptop run Windows 11.

Comment: The first thing I'd do is run an antimalware scan. The second thing I'd do, if the malware scan comes up clean, is run the System File Checker.

Comment: I run Norton AV and have already run sfc with no problems reported. It has to be an application that has been installed that is the issue I just cannot identify the culprit. I have looked through the processes running but it is not obvious what is the cause.